# Rank function with complex scenario

Tags: sql, rank, dense-rank, analytical

[image]

I have a TAble TABLE1 and having columns like ID, Status and Code

BAsed on the code priority i want the output , the priority is

SS -> RR - > TT - > AA ( these priority is not stored in any tables)

Query should first look for Approved status then we need to check for Code column
Example1:
ID: 2345 - This record having Approved status for all the codes like SS , AA and RR
and based on the code priority SS should be pulled in the output as 2345, SS

Example2:
ID: 3333- This record having Approved status for all the codes like RR and TT
and based on the code priority RR should be pulled in the output as 3333, RR

ID: 4444- Eventhough this record is having Codes like SS and RR but it is status column is having value as TERMED so we need to populate the next priority in the list and output should display as 4444 TT

ID: 5555- None of the status for this ID is having Approved status all are having status as Termed so based on the priority in the output 5555,SS should be picked as this one is the priority

so output for 2345 and 5555 is same only the difference is if none of the record having approved status then only we should go for Termed - if the record is only having termed then based on priority record should be pulled

Attached the picture for reference

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `RANK` along with a `CASE` expression for ordering:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                        ORDER BY CASE Status WHEN 'Approved' THEN 1
                                             WHEN 'Termed'   THEN 2
                                             ELSE 3 END,
                                 CASE Code WHEN 'SS' THEN 1
                                           WHEN 'RR' THEN 2
                                           WHEN 'TT' THEN 3
                                           WHEN 'AA' THEN 4 END) rnk
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE Status = 'Approved'
)

SELECT ID, Code
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: if the id is having both TERMED and APPROVED status then we have to check for approved and get the record based on the priority -- if the id is having only TERMED status for all the codes then based on the pirority output should populate for example Example4: ID: 5555- This record having TERMED status for all the codes like RR and TT and based on the code priority RR should be pulled in the output as 5555, RR

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data explaining this new requirement.

Comment: @Ram I have edited with what I think is your desired logic.  I only added a second sort layer to the `ORDER BY` clause of `RANK`.

Comment: it is not working if the ID is having both status like 'APPROVED' or 'TERMED'  - as my requirement is first query should look for Approved status ...if record is not having any termed status then in that termed status record should be based on the priority record shoudl be fetch - let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table table1 (id, status, code) as
select 2345, 'Approved', 'SS' from dual union all
select 2345, 'Approved', 'AA' from dual union all
select 2345, 'Approved', 'RR' from dual union all
select 3333, 'Approved', 'RR' from dual union all
select 3333, 'Approved', 'TT' from dual union all
select 4444, 'TERMED', 'SS' from dual union all
select 4444, 'TERMED', 'RR' from dual union all
select 4444, 'Approved', 'TT' from dual
;

select ID, CODE
from (
  select ID, STATUS, CODE
    , row_number()over( 
            partition by ID 
            order by status
                     , decode(code, 'SS', 1, 'RR', 2, 'TT', 3, 'AA', 4) ) rank
  from table1
)
where rank = 1
;
```